# Drupal 7 different urls with same information

Tags: uri

I have a new drupal site,it was built by other website designer.Now i got a problem for the url.There are some different url with same information.For example:
"/taxonomy/term/31/0" and "/projects/led-tunnel-lighting".I only need the url like "/projects/led-tunnel-lighting".
Please tell me how to fix this problem.Thank you very much!
I was a novice of drupal.

Comment: Please tell us why it causes you problems and what would you considered "fix". In the meantime I can only suggest Global Redirect. But it's a wild guess, nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your two URLs are the same, but one is the system URL and the other one the aliases URL. They are both valid and normal to have, but in that case what you need is this module:
[Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect)

> an alias provides a nice clean URL for a path on a site. However
>   Drupal does not remove the old path (eg node/1234). The problem is
>   that you now have two URLs representing the same content.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to link to a node or a term (or something else in which might have an URL-Alias), use the [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) function. The link to the term will then be rewritten to the given URL-Alias (as long as there is one).

Comment: Thank you for your help.But What is the  l() function?

Comment: Maybe you read on the linked page a bit. I can't explain better as it is written there.